# How can I get notified of errors during when piping to gulp browserify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify, gulp-notify

I am using **browserify** so I can use npm modules in my front end code, and **gulp** to do my build tasks. This works fine:

```
var browserify = require('gulp-browserify');

gulp.task('js', ['clean'], function() {
    gulp
        .src('./public/js/src/index.js')
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals : true,
            debug : ! gulp.env.production
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/dist'))
});
```

However if there's a syntax error in my JS, I'd like to be notified of the error via an OS X notification. I've seen this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161387/catching-browserify-parse-error-standalone-option) and modified my code to add an `.on('error'...)` after the `.browserify()`:

```
// Browserify/bundle the JS.
gulp
    .src('./public/js/src/index.js')
    .pipe(browserify({
        insertGlobals : true,
        debug : ! gulp.env.production
    }).on('error', function(err){
        notify.onError({
            message: "Error: <%= error.message %>",
            title: "Failed running browserify"
        }
        this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/js/dist'))
```

However this doesn't notify when my JS is broken. Adding a console.log() inside `on('error',...)` doesn't log either. I suspect because that question doesn't involve using gulp piping.

**How can I get notified of errors during when piping to gulp browserify?**

Comment: Do you use browserify util or gulp-browerify plugin? In my browserify task i use browserify util and it inform me when js has errors.

Comment: @Alexander Actually I think you've just answered the question. From my gulpfile: `var browserify = require('gulp-browserify')` which is no longer maintained - see https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-browserify. The proper thing looks to be to use another package. Do you want to post that as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **gulp-notify**. Note also you should use the [browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) module instead of the deprecated [gulp-browerify](https://github.com/deepak1556/gulp-browserify) module.

```
var browserify = require('browserify'),
    brfs = require('brfs'),
    watchify = require('watchify'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify");


var bundler = watchify(browserify({
    basedir: "./public/js/src"
}));


// Browserify our code
gulp.task('js', ['clean'], function() {
    // Browserify/bundle the JS.
    return bundler.bundle()
        // log errors if they happen
        .on('error', function(err) {
            return notify().write(err);
        })
        .pipe(source('index.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public/js/dist'));
});
```

[Here](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/browserify-uglify-sourcemap.md) example how to use `browserify` util in `gulp` task.

[Here](https://github.com/greypants/gulp-starter/blob/master/gulp/tasks/browserify.js) another example how to use `browserify` and show notification, when js has syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

In my gulpfile, I just listen for uncaught exceptions and notify using [node-notifier](https://npmjs.org/package/node-notifier):

```
var Notifier = require('node-notifier');
notifier = new Notifier();

process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  notifier.notify({title: 'error', message: 'gulp process has crashed'});

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.error(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }, 1000);
});
```

I found that a `setTimeout` delay was necessary for the notification to show up before exiting the process.

Comment: Ack, I'm currently using `gulp-notify` per the tag. I'd like to have specific (and different) messages for different errors - eg, sass, vs browserify errors. Thanks (and upmodded) though!

Answer (score 0):

I use gulp-plumber for all my error catching:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function(){
    return browserify('./assets/js/src/app.js')
            .pipe(plugins.plumber())
            .pipe(gulp.dest('./assets/js'))
            .pipe(plugins.notify({message: "browserify complete"}))
});
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber

You might also have to use gulp-streamify. I don't think browserify supports streams out of the box. It's been some time since I tried browserify with gulp so I'm not sure my code snippet will work out of the box, sorry for that.

https://github.com/nfroidure/gulp-streamify