# Have Browserify transform Hintify continue on error

Tags: gulp, browserify, jshint

I'm using Gulp with [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify) and [Hintify](https://github.com/ansis/hintify). The [standard](http://latviancoder.com/story/error-handling-browserify-gulp) [way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161387/catching-browserify-parse-error-standalone-option) to catch errors seems to be something like:

```
browserify({
    entries: 'app.js',
    transform: [
        // Some other transforms
        plugins.hintify
    ]
    // A bunch of other settings
}).bundle()
    // Error handling
    .on('error', function(error) {
        util.beep(); // Util is gulp-util
        util.log(error);
        this.emit('end');
    })
    .pipe(...)
```

This works great, and everytime I violate my `jshint` I get something like this:

```
Users/me/Sites/project/client/scripts/app.js: line 11, col 23, Missing semicolon.
```

And the build stops.

However, I'd kinda like the build to *continue* even if I forget a semicolon. Right now, any `jshint` error stops the build from processing. I like to check if my code is up to par, but it shouldn't prevent everything from building if I have an unused argument in a function.

Help?

Comment: Have you seen [this post](https://isimmons.github.io/)? Perhaps it does what you want. I see that [jshint](https://gist.github.com/connor/1597131) has a `maxerr` property

Answer (score 2):

The current setup works for me (configuration sam as [here](https://isimmons.github.io/)):

```
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var stylish = require('jshint-stylish')
...
.pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
//.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail')) // <- omit a fail reporter 
...
```

OR

```
...
.pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'))
.pipe(jshint.reporter('fail'))
.on('error', notify.onError({ message: 'JS hint fail'})) // <- pipe fail to notification
...
```

This gives me the output:

```
...
src\m\typings.js
  line 0   col 0   ES5 option is now set per default
  line 3   col 18  ['SUCCESS'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 4   col 18  ['FAILURE'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 5   col 18  ['UNSTABLE'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 6   col 18  ['NOT_BUILT'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 10  col 26  ['info'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 11  col 26  ['success'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 12  col 26  ['mark'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 13  col 26  ['warn'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 14  col 26  ['error'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 15  col 26  ['debug'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 16  col 26  ['none'] is better written in dot notation.
  line 18  col 1   Unnecessary semicolon.

  ‼  13 warnings

[10:08:32] src\m\typings.js

src\helper\scaffolding.helper.js
  line 0    col 0    ES5 option is now set per default
  line 65   col 61   Regular parameters cannot come after default parameters.
  line 82   col 79   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 84   col 77   Regular parameters cannot come after default parameters.
  line 90   col 39   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 91   col 21   Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 91   col 60   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 105  col 46   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 106  col 29   Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 106  col 103  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 3    col 12   'require' is not defined.
  line 4    col 14   'require' is not defined.
  line 5    col 11   'require' is not defined.
  line 6    col 19   'require' is not defined.
  line 7    col 10   'require' is not defined.
  line 8    col 13   'require' is not defined.
  line 9    col 13   'require' is not defined.
  line 33   col 17   'none' is not defined.
  line 42   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 45   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 48   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 51   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 54   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 57   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 60   col 13   'color' is not defined.
  line 63   col 12   'color' is not defined.
  line 85   col 25   'process' is not defined.

  ×  2 errors
  ‼  25 warnings

[10:08:32] src\helper\scaffolding.helper.js

src\helper\scaffolding.server.js
  line 0   col 0    ES5 option is now set per default
  line 22  col 44   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 23  col 25   Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 23  col 75   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 25  col 43   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 26  col 25   Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 26  col 117  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 38  col 40   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 39  col 21   Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 39  col 50   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 74  col 43   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 75  col 25   Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 75  col 96   Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 4   col 12   'require' is not defined.
  line 5   col 13   'require' is not defined.
  line 7   col 13   'require' is not defined.

  ‼  16 warnings

[10:08:32] src\helper\scaffolding.server.js

src\server\publish.js
  line 0   col 0   ES5 option is now set per default
  line 17  col 17  Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 17  col 54  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 29  col 21  Missing 'new' prefix when invoking a constructor.
  line 29  col 44  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
  line 3   col 12  'require' is not defined.
  line 4   col 13  'require' is not defined.
  line 7   col 14  'require' is not defined.
  line 9   col 12  'require' is not defined.
  line 10  col 10  'require' is not defined.
  line 11  col 14  'require' is not defined.
  line 12  col 13  'require' is not defined.

  ‼  12 warnings
[10:08:32] gulp-notify: [Error running Gulp] JS hint fail
[10:08:32] src\server\publish.js
[10:08:32] Finished 'build' after 1.61 s
```

with jshint `^1.12.0`

Comment: Yeah, I used to use a similar setup, which I can make work no problem. But as soon as I'm trying to use Browserify transforms - hintify - I run into the problem above.

Comment: I am not familiar withg browserify, but maybe [this post](https://gist.github.com/mlouro/8886076) describes a similar setup?

Comment: They're also using [gulp-jshint](https://github.com/spalger/gulp-jshint) and not [hintify](https://github.com/ansis/hintify). That's basically the same setup as you described and as I've used up until now. However, I wonder if this is possible with `hintify` only...

Comment: Undortunately this is as far as my knowlegde reaches. Sorry that I can't be of any help