# See code creating Browserify errors (from fake_...js) by outputting code to console or viewing fake_.js file

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I can catch errors from Browserify (as shown by other [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23161387/catching-browserify-parse-error-standalone-option) on this topic), however I need to see the **specific code causing the error**. Example:

```
Error: Parsing file /public/javascripts/lib/fake_7af951da.js: 
Line 10: Spread must be the final element of an element list //<--? need details
```

I want to output to the console the specific code in the fake_.js file that is causing the error, or I need to be able to view the fake_.js file so that I can look at Line 10.

Here is my gulp info:

```
gulp.task('browserify', function() {
    // Single entry point to browserify
    gulp.src('./public/javascripts/lib/*.js') //lists files to require
        .pipe(browserify({
            insertGlobals : true,
            debug : !gulp.env.production
        }))
        .on('error', function(err){
    console.log(err.stack);  
  })
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/javascripts/out.js'))
});
```